# My unique_ptr implementation

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, pointers, raii

This is my simple unique_ptr implementation. Anything that could be improved upon or should be added?

```
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
class unique_ptr
{
private:
    T * ptr_resource = nullptr;
public:
    // Safely constructs resource. Operator new is called by the user. Once constructed the unique_ptr will own the resource.
    // std::move is used because it is used to indicate that an object may be moved from other resource.
    explicit unique_ptr(T* raw_resource) noexcept : ptr_resource(std::move(raw_resource)) {}
    unique_ptr(std::nullptr_t) : ptr_resource(nullptr) {}

    // destroys the resource when object goes out of scope
    ~unique_ptr() noexcept
    {
        delete ptr_resource;
    }
    // Disables the copy/ctor and copy assignment operator. We cannot have two copies exist or it'll bypass the RAII concept.
    unique_ptr(const unique_ptr<T>&) noexcept = delete;
    unique_ptr& operator = (const unique_ptr&) noexcept = delete;
public:
    // releases the ownership of the resource. The user is now responsible for memory clean-up.
    T* release() noexcept
    {
        T* resource_ptr = this->ptr_resource;
        this->ptr_resource = nullptr;

        return resource_ptr;
    }
    // returns a pointer to the resource
    T* get() const noexcept
    {
        return ptr_resource;
    }
    // swaps the resources
    void swap(unique_ptr<T>& resource_ptr) noexcept
    {
        std::swap(ptr_resource, resource_ptr.ptr_resource);
    }
    // replaces the resource. the old one is destroyed and a new one will take it's place.
    void reset(T* resource_ptr) noexcept(false)
    {
        // ensure a invalid resource is not passed or program will be terminated
        if (resource_ptr == nullptr)
            throw std::invalid_argument("An invalid pointer was passed, resources will not be swapped");

        delete ptr_resource;

        ptr_resource = nullptr;

        std::swap(ptr_resource, resource_ptr);
    }
public:
    // operators
    T* operator->() const noexcept
    {
        return this->ptr_resource;
    }
    T& operator*() const noexcept
    {
        return *this->ptr_resource;
    }
    // May be used to check for nullptr
};
```

Comment: Please read my series on smart pointers for some help: https://lokiastari.com/series/

Answer (score 7):

- Let me first assume that your `unique_ptr` is supposed to be movable. Then, any basic test case whould have unrevealed this:

  ```
  unique_ptr<int> ptr1(new int());
  unique_ptr<int> ptr2 = std::move(ptr1); // Fails to compile
  ```

  Recall that `= delete`-ing special member functions means user-declaring them. And user-declared copy and copy assignment constructors prevent compiler-generated move (assignment) constructors! You have to manually define them. This case is by the way covered by the [rule of five/C.21 Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c21-if-you-define-or-delete-any-default-operation-define-or-delete-them-all), and also have a look at the table posted in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24512883/9593596) for an overview of compiler-generated/-deleted/not-declared special member functions.
- Is the non-availability of an implicit conversion to `bool` intended? Checking if a (smart) pointer is in an empty/null state is so common in ordinary control flow statements that clients will expect this to compile:

  ```
  unique_ptr<SomeType> ptr = ...;

  if (ptr) ... // currently fails to compile
  ```

  But not that this might be debatable. Implicit conversions can cause a lot of pain, so if you intend to not allow them for the sake of a more explicit

  ```
  if (ptr == nullptr) ...
  ```

  that's a design decision. But one that should be documented in a comment at the top of the class.
- Except the non-`explicit`-ness of the second constructor (thanks to @Deduplicator for pointing that out) taking a `std::nullptr_t`, it is superfluous. You can construct an empty `unique_ptr` by

  ```
  unique_ptr<SomeType> empty{nullptr};
  ```

  which simply invokes the first constructor taking a `T*` argument. I would remove the second constructor.
- ... and add a default constructor that initializes `ptr_resource` to `nullptr`, as

  ```
  unique_tr<SomeType> empty;
  ```

  might be a way of constructing an empty smart pointer that users would expect to compile.
- Move-constructing the `ptr_resource` in the constructor initializer by `ptr_resource(std::move(raw_resource))` doesn't make much sense. Just copy the pointer instead. The comment `// std::move is used because it is used to indicate that an object may be moved from other resource.` is rather confusing, because `T* raw_resource` is already a pointer, and hence a *handle* to a resource, not the resource itself.
- The `release` member function can be implemented more conveniently as

  ```
  T* release() noexcept
  {
      return std::exchange(ptr_resource, nullptr);
  }
  ```
- I wouln't let the `reset` member function throw when the input is a `nullptr`. Why shouldn't it be allowed to `reset` a `unique_ptr` with a `nullptr`, turning it back into an empty state?
- The only facilities you use from the standard library are `std::move` and `std::swap`. Those are in `<utility>`, so you don't need to include `<algorithm>`, which is probably much heavier in terms of compile times.
- I would omit the `this->` prefix, it's unnecessarily verbose. But that might be a matter of taste.
- Have you considered custom deleters? This makes the class template more reusable in scenarios other than pointers to heap resources, e.g. closing a file upon destruction etc.